# Responding to keypress and mouse click on fully-transparent panel

Tags: c#, keyboard, mouse, transparency

I've created a form that's maximized over the entire screen.

Within that form, and sized to fill the entire form, I've placed a panel with background color set to `Red`.  The form's `TransparencyKey` is set to `Red`.

Therefore, the Panel is like a "keyhole" - you can see the desktop that's directly underneath it.

When the user clicks on the panel, OR, presses a key on the keyboard, I want to take action.

But, because the panel is completely transparent, when it is clicked or a key is pressed, nothing happens.  If I make the panel non-transparent (setting it's background color to Blue, for example), it does respond to clicks.

**What's the best way to get the panel to respond to clicks and keypresses?**

Do I have to hook all mouse an keyboard events on the entire system or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that I can use `GetAsyncKeyState` to respond to both keypresses and mouse clicks.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
```

Then, I can call `GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)` and `GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Escape)`, for example.  Much simpler than hooking all keyboard and mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

The panel does not take in text input, you can set your main form to handle the keypress event.

```
this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.form_KeyPress);
```

http://screensnapr.com/v/VovWAi.png

As for getting the mouse location on your panel, you can use the mouseclick event

```
this.panel1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseClick);
```

http://screensnapr.com/v/DB3kCQ.png

I have tested it, and it works on a fullsize transparent panel

Comment: That only works on Aero.  On XP or with Aero disabled, the panel is transparent to mouse clicks.  The Aero behavior is a bug but has been around unfixed long enough to become a 'feature'.

Comment: @Hans-Passant Know of any techniques that will work on XP or with Aero disabled?